# creating multi rows depend on special conditions

Tags: r

I have data.frame as follows :

```
duration    classlabel
 100           W
 120           1
 390           2
  30           3
  30           2
 150           3
  30           4
  60           3
  60           4
  30           3
 120           4
  30           3
 120           4
```

I have to make a number of lines according to duration with the class label in R. as an example, I have to make 100 rows with the class label 'W', and then 120 rows with the class label '2', etc. 
anyone, can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `uncount`

```
library(tidyr)
uncount(df1, duration, .remove = FALSE)
```

---

Or with `rep` from `base R` to replicate the sequence of rows by 'duration' column and expand the rows based on the numeric index

```
df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), df1$duration),]
```